# Bind backspace to nothing in zsh

Tags: zsh, konsole

I'm trying to bind my backspace key to nothing in Konsole (you might ask why, well, I'm trying to get rid of the habbit of pressing Backspace and instead use Ctrl+8, which is closer to my hands).

I don't get how to bind the backspace key to nothing, i.e.:

```
bindkey '^H' <nothing>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Surely this is something you want to configure in Konsole (or your window manager) itself, not `zsh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about binding it to the empty string with

```
bindkey -s "^H" ""
```

Works here with zsh 5.0.2.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason my mind couldn't comprehend something this simple!! I thought there would be something more complex like a <NOP> in vim :). Thank you!!!